# Smartface 4.5 Location info

Tags: smartface.io

Following code gives compile error in order to get location info from gps for smartface 4.5 for android and ios.
How to get loctaion with SMF 4.5?

```
// Get location
* @this SMF.Net.Eventsfunction Global_Events_OnLocationChanged(e){
alert(e.lat);
alert(e.lng);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set GPS status as true before Global_Events_OnLocationChanged event.

```
Device.setGPSStatus(true);

* @this SMF.Net.Events
*/
function Global_Events_OnLocationChanged(e){
   alert("myLat : " + e.lat);
   alert("myLng :" + e.lng);
}
```

Comment: Yes I already did but not working! The code gives itself error when it is debuged!

Comment: SytanxError:Unexpected token '*'

Comment: did you write like that : * @this SMF.Net.Eventsfunction Global_Events_OnLocationChanged(e){

Comment: Yes! It is automatic edited code when you click on global events.

Comment: It works for iOS but not Android! You could able to do for Android?